# How to send email from localhost using PHP with XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp, smtp

I want to send Gmail mail using PHP with Xampp from localhost. I try to see the tutorial via Youtube. But it is still not working even I follow step by step. My PHP code is as follow:

```
<?php
mail('mypersonalemail@gmail.com','Testing send email using PHP','Content 
here','From: otheremail@gmail.com');
?>
```

I also did some Xampp configuration in my "php.ini" file and "sendmail.ini" as shown below:

1) php.ini:

```
    [mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/smtp
    SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
    ; http://php.net/smtp-port
    smtp_port=587

    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-from
    sendmail_from = mypersonalemail@gmail.com
    sendmail_path = "\"D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

2) sendmail.ini:

```
    smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port=587
    auth_username=mypersonalemail@gmail.com
    auth_password=mygmailpassword
```

And my file location of the PHP file is C:\xampp\htdocs\testemail.php

I run the localhost with http://localhost/testemail.php. I also have tried change the port number to 25, 587 and 465. Guide me if I missing something.

Comment: are you sure you do not to do any changes to your gmail acconut? maybe about security?

Comment: I have change the gmail account setting already

Comment: Please use php mailer library

Comment: The `mail` function is not the right tool for this task. Mailer like phpmailer and Zend\Mail has support for mailing via SSL/TLS.

Comment: Could you try all the steps from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/8532801) ?

Comment: download phpmailer( https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer ) and check with this https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582147-How-to-Send-with-PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FeedBack Form With Email Functionality</title>
<link href="css/elements.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!-- Body Starts Here -->
<body>
<div class="container">
<!-- Feedback Form Starts Here -->
<div id="feedback">
<!-- Heading Of The Form -->
<div class="head">
<h3>FeedBack Form</h3>
<p>This is feedback form. Send us your feedback !</p>
</div>
<!-- Feedback Form -->
<form action="#" id="form" method="post" name="form">
<input name="vname" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" value="">
<input name="vemail" placeholder="Your Email" type="text" value="">
<input name="sub" placeholder="Subject" type="text" value="">
<label>Your Suggestion/Feedback</label>
<textarea name="msg" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea>
<input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Feedback">
</form>
<h3><?php include "secure_email_code.php"?></h3>
</div>
<!-- Feedback Form Ends Here -->
</div>
</body>
<!-- Body Ends Here -->
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
// Checking For Blank Fields..
if($_POST["vname"]==""||$_POST["vemail"]==""||$_POST["sub"]==""||$_POST["msg"]==""){
echo "Fill All Fields..";
}else{
// Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
$email=$_POST['vemail'];
// Sanitize E-mail Address
$email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// Validate E-mail Address
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
}
else{
$subject = $_POST['sub'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];
$headers = 'From:'. $email2 . "rn"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email2 . "rn"; // Carbon copy to Sender
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
mail("recievers_mail_id@xyz.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your feedback";
}
}
}
?>
```

CSS for the HTML Part

```
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway";
/*----------------------------------------------
CSS Settings For HTML Div ExactCenter
------------------------------------------------*/
h3,p,label {
text-align:center;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
color:#006400
}
h2 {
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif
}
input {
width:100%;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:5px;
height:30px;
box-shadow:1px 1px 12px gray;
border-radius:3px;
border:none
}
textarea {
width:100%;
height:80px;
margin-top:10px;
padding:5px;
box-shadow:1px 1px 12px gray;
border-radius:3px
}
#send {
width:103%;
height:45px;
margin-top:40px;
border-radius:3px;
background-color:#cd853f;
border:1px solid #fff;
color:#fff;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
font-size:18px
}
div#feedback {
text-align:center;
height:520px;
width:330px;
padding:20px 25px 20px 15px;
background-color:#f3f3f3;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #cd853f;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
float:left
}
.container {
width:960px;
margin:40px auto
}
```

Comment: In the HTML, what do you mean by the line <h3><?php include "secure_email_code.php"?></h3>

Comment: is it secure_email_code.php is just the name that you give for the PHP file for your previous answer in this question?

Comment: include "secure_email_code.php" means that the php is included and this php starts. The PHP part I have done in a separate file called secure_email_code.php

Answer (score 0):

Try send with PHPMailer it is simple solution

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

Works with TLS/SSL smtp connections (gmail need TLS connections)